# JavaScript and 'this' inside immediately executed functions

Tags: javascript

I have been reading up on the intricacies of 'this' in JavaScript. Given this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.dir(this);
    (function foo() {
        console.dir(this);
    })();
});
```

In Chrome, the console shows the first 'this' as an 'HTMLDocument' (as I expected), but the second 'this' is 'undefined'. Can someone point me to a good explanation of why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/puptV/ alerts `DOMWindow`

Comment: I don't `this` can ever be undefined (in a web browser).  If it's not set to something (using `call` or `apply`, it should always be `window`).

Comment: It is definitely undefined, BUT, Igor and Simon's comments are correct. There is a bunch of <script> ahead of this which I assumed to be not relevant, but if I remove all of it, it emits 'DOMWindow' as they claim. So clearly they are right.

Comment: @Rocket:  `undefined` is the default in *strict mode*.

Comment: Aha, indeed, yes, the 'something else' is 'use strict'. TIL yet another subtle thing about 'use strict'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way in which a javascript function is invoked changes the meaning of `this` inside of it.  Here you've invoked a method which isn't associated with any object hence it has no `this` value to bind to.

In the first case the callback is being invoked via JQuery and they are manipulating the callback such that `this` points to the `document` DOM element.  It's easy to visualize this as your callback being invoked with apply

```
yourCallback.apply(document, null);
```

You can fix the second version like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.dir(this);
    var that = this;
    (function foo() {
        console.dir(that);
    })();
});
```

Or another way using `apply`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.dir(this);
    (function foo() {
        console.dir(this);
    }).apply(this, null);
});
```

Comment: or you could do `(function() {..}).call(this)` rather then `(function() {..})()`

Comment: @MattBriggs added the apply version.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the context with which the current function has been called.

- When calling a function with the object.method() syntax, `object` become the context.
- When calling a function with the function() syntax, there is no context: it's null.

jQuery calls your ready function with `document` as the context. And you call your immediately executed function without context, which is why it's null.

You can do this:

```
// assign `this` to that so you can access `this` through `that`
var that = this; 
(function foo() {
    console.log(that);
}());
```

Or this:

```
// bind the function to `this` and then call it
$.proxy(function() { 
    console.log(this);
}, this)();
```

See [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Or even this:

```
// call the function with `this` as context
(function() { 
    console.log(this);
}).call(this);
```

See [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of $.proxy but am not totally clear on when it is necessary and when it's not. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If that code is put into the console of a page with jQuery loaded, the second "this" is DOMWindow, which is the global "this". It is **not** undefined.

There must be something else on your page.

Comment: True! My apologies. Still a lot of good insights for me in these replies.

Answer (score 0):

The second `this` is in an anonymous function which has no context. `this` is always an implicit variable at the function level, so your inner functions `this` is shadowing the outer `this`